# What am I doing wrong in Java?

Tags: java

I'm brand new to coding. When I run the following in eclipse, I cannot get what I want. The issue is the line: `System.out.println("\nThe change for " + amount + "  cents is: " );`

The "amount" should be whatever the user inputs. Instead, whenever I run it I get "0"

What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class lab2part3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int DOLLAR_VALUE = 100;
        final int HALFDOLLAR_VALUE = 50;
        final int QUARTER_VALUE = 25;
        final int DIME_VALUE = 10;
        final int NICKEL_VALUE = 5;
        final int PENNY_VALUE = 1;

        String input = null;


         Scanner console = new Scanner ( System.in );
         System.out.println("\nEnter the amount in cents:");
         int amount = console.nextInt();

         int nDollars = amount/DOLLAR_VALUE; 
         amount %= DOLLAR_VALUE;

         int nHalfDollars = amount/HALFDOLLAR_VALUE; 
         amount %= HALFDOLLAR_VALUE;

         int nQuarterDollars = amount/QUARTER_VALUE; 
         amount %= QUARTER_VALUE;

         int nDimes = amount/DIME_VALUE; 
         amount %= DIME_VALUE;

         int nNickels = amount/NICKEL_VALUE; 
         amount %= NICKEL_VALUE;

         int nPennys = amount/PENNY_VALUE; 
         amount %= PENNY_VALUE;



         System.out.println("\nThe change for " + amount + "  cents is: " );

         System.out.println("Dollars = "+nDollars); 

         System.out.println("Half-Dollars = "+nHalfDollars); 

         System.out.println("Quarters = "+nQuarterDollars); 

         System.out.println("Dimes = "+nDimes); 

         System.out.println("Nickels = "+nNickels);

         System.out.println("Pennies = "+nPennys);

    }
}
```

Comment: `amount %= DOLLAR_VALUE;` What do you think this does?

Comment: Specifically this one: `amount %= PENNY_VALUE` - The remainder when you divide *anything* by `1` is `0`.

Comment: I'm curious what input you use.  You say you get "0" but what did you type in for input?  What happens if you type in "100" exactly, say, or "123"?

Answer (score 2):

Every time you make the line `amount %= ANY_VALUE` you actually run the next line:
`amount = amount % ANY_VALUE` which means you decrease the value of `amount`.
you could save the value of amount before the calculations in an another variable, and than printing that value.for example:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class lab2part3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int DOLLAR_VALUE = 100;
        final int HALFDOLLAR_VALUE = 50;
        final int QUARTER_VALUE = 25;
        final int DIME_VALUE = 10;
        final int NICKEL_VALUE = 5;
        final int PENNY_VALUE = 1;

        String input = null;


         Scanner console = new Scanner ( System.in );
         System.out.println("\nEnter the amount in cents:");
         int amount = console.nextInt();
         int startingAmount = amount;  
         int nDollars = amount/DOLLAR_VALUE; 
         amount %= DOLLAR_VALUE;

         int nHalfDollars = amount/HALFDOLLAR_VALUE; 
         amount %= HALFDOLLAR_VALUE;

         int nQuarterDollars = amount/QUARTER_VALUE; 
         amount %= QUARTER_VALUE;

         int nDimes = amount/DIME_VALUE; 
         amount %= DIME_VALUE;

         int nNickels = amount/NICKEL_VALUE; 
         amount %= NICKEL_VALUE;

         int nPennys = amount/PENNY_VALUE; 
         amount %= PENNY_VALUE;



         System.out.println("\nThe change for " + startingAmount + "  cents is: " );

         System.out.println("Dollars = "+nDollars); 

         System.out.println("Half-Dollars = "+nHalfDollars); 

         System.out.println("Quarters = "+nQuarterDollars); 

         System.out.println("Dimes = "+nDimes); 

         System.out.println("Nickels = "+nNickels);

         System.out.println("Pennies = "+nPennys);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually produces correct output at least some of the time.  I think you might have a problem in your environment (i.e., with Eclipse).

Make the following changes to your code.  Remove the line where you read `amount` from the scanner and just set it to 123;

```
  String input = null;

  Scanner console = new Scanner( System.in );
  System.out.println( "\nEnter the amount in cents:" );
  // TEST
//      int amount = console.nextInt();
  int amount = 123;
```

Tell us the result.  I get output that looks correct.